# Android opengl-es 1.x make a simple water/ocean effect

Tags: opengl-es

Is there an easy way to make a water/ocean effect?

thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is no. Or better, it depends on what you mean for "Simple" and what you mean for "Ocean effect" and on what is the quality of the effect it is acceptable for you.

Consider that water surface simulation is one of the toughest things you could have to achieve and it involves a lot of mathematics behind.

The best tutorial/article you can find on this matter comes from NVIDIA GPU Gems that you can find online for free (thanks NVIDIA):

http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html

I hope this helps in some way.